# Burp Suite Integration with Azure CI/CD Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, cicd, burp

What is the process for integrating Burp Suite Enterprise Edition with the Azure DevOps CI/CD platform, considering the absence of any available plugins in the Azure Marketplace?

Comment: By invoking its CLI? https://portswigger.net/burp/documentation/desktop/getting-started/launch-from-command-line Assuming it's been installed on the agent. WHat have you tried and what issues are you encountering. Wrapping the CLI into an extension dhould be relatively easy and creating a tool-installer is also not too much work. The biggest problem is probably setting up the license if one is needed to run the CLI.

Comment: Or these docs: https://portswigger.net/burp/documentation/enterprise/integrate-ci-cd-platforms/generic

Comment: Thanks for the response @jessehouwing. I am new to these integrations with Azure, so what do you mean by "wrapping the CLI into an extension or creating a tool installer"?

Comment: An extension is a small piece of script that then often just calls the already existing CLI tool provided by the vendor. A tool installer is a specific kind of script that downloads the binary and puts it in the place where it's needed. There are many similar extensions on the marketplace. You don't actually have to publish an extension if you just push a custom task into your collection.. If you want to take that direction, update your question and I can add a set of steps to get you started.

Comment: The objective is to integrate Burp enterprise with Azure and gain insight into how the scan is triggered, particularly behind the scenes. Could you please provide guidance on the necessary steps to follow in the pipeline, from beginning to end?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.